# I cant makethe window to act and look as i want

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to make a password generator app. i have this code here, but it doesn't work properly.

I have tried some solutions I found on the internet, but none of them works, they all use [sys library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) , which I don't want to use.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import random

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton('Generate password')
def on_button_clicked():
    alert = QMessagebog()
    alert.setText(password)
    alert.exec_()
button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec_()

chars = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789'

lenght = int(input('Choose lenght: '))

password=''

for c in range(lenght):
 password += random.choice(chars)
print(password)
```

I expect the program to open a window with a button and when the button is clicked it will show the generated password in a text-field in the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import random

app    = QApplication([])

w = QWidget()
s = QSpinBox()
s.setRange(7, 20)
button = QPushButton('Generate password')
lay = QVBoxLayout(w)
lay.addWidget(s)
lay.addWidget(button)

def on_button_clicked(): 
    chars = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789'

#    lenght = int(input('Choose lenght: '))
    lenght = s.value() 

    password = ''
    for c in range(lenght):
        password += random.choice(chars)

    alert = QMessageBox()                           # QMessagebog()
    alert.setText(password)
    alert.exec_()

w.show()

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)

app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: If my example helped you, remember to mark it as the right decision.